# How time zone differences affect play time of early access N-day window?

Tags: starfield

I have seen a couple of game developers that grant early access for their video games N days before release date noting that "actual game time is subject to applicable time zone differences". An example of this is COD MW3 for which I saw the above mentioned note. I have also seen someone on another forum for Starfield(which also had early access for 5 days before global release) complaining how they will only have around 4 days of game time total due to them being from Australia, but that doesn't make sense to me. Can anyone explain why game developers add these notes?

Comment: Interesting question! Maybe a moderator can migrate this to GameDev, where it is (more) on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

My brother and I both got the Premium edition of "Starfield", so we were both able to start playing the game early access. My brother lives in the US Eastern Time Zone; I live in the US Mountain Time Zone. Eastern Time is 2 hours ahead of Mountain Time.

Early access was opened at 8:00 pm -- local time. When my brother began playing Starfield, I was left waiting an extra 2 hours before I could play myself.

Why do game developers do this? I couldn't say. But as a software engineer, I can attest that time zones are Hard to deal with (uppercase H). Instead of calculating an instant in time and adjusting for time zones, daylight savings, leap years, leap seconds, and so on, it was probably a lot easier to just say "you get access at 8:00 p.m. local time".

Places like Niue and American Samoa loses out, unfortunately, but New Zealand thinks this is a great policy. ;)

Comment: What do you mean by local time? Was it released at 8 pm in each time zone in the world?

Comment: Yes that's what I said. My brother started playing at 8pm eastern but I had to wait until 8pm mountain, 2 hours later.

Comment: How would Australia lose out in that case? If anything they would start playing first.

Comment: Time zones are hard and I misread the map. 